# Warning: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI… in DispatcherServlet with name

Tags: spring-mvc

Already, I checked out nearly every relevant article on stackoverflow, but I couldn't fix it.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
version="3.1">

<servlet>
  <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="tutorial.mvc" />

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

TestController.java

```
package tutorial.mvc;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class TestController {
    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public String test(){
        return "view";
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>MavenAngularSpringHibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>MavenAngularSpringHibernate</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging><!-- Since it is a web project, packaging specified as "war" -->

    <name>MavenAngularSpringHibernate</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
                <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.6.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
</project>
```

Having view.jsp inside jsp folder. Please find the path below:
/MavenAngularSpringHibernate/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/view.jsp

Having web.xml and mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml inside WEB-INF folder. Please find the path below:
/MavenAngularSpringHibernate/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml
/MavenAngularSpringHibernate/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml

On hitting the following url,

http://localhost:8080/MavenAngularSpringHibernate/test

I am getting the below error:

WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/MavenAngularSpringHibernate/test] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'

I've checked out dozens of articles like this, but I just couldn't find the mistake, anybody has any idea what could it be?

Comment: show your maven file please

Comment: I have not found any issue with your code.Looks fine .. may be you should refer this answer.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40865887/http-status-404-spring-mvc-login?noredirect=1#comment68949293_40865887 . Alberto's answer at last.Hope this can help you

Comment: @ScanQR - Please find pom.xml. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: @Darshit - I don't find solution with the link you given. Thanks.

Comment: I got solution. class file was not generated inside [PROJECT_NAME]\target\classes directory.